# Каталог магазина, размеры php Mysql?

Tags: php, sql

Озадачили сделать ИМ с массой прибамбасов, со всем разобрался кроме вывода доступных размеров в каталоге: как пример ( 42...52)
[image: 5a859d8fe9c04013721327.pngUvvpmu11.png]
Основной затык - количество этих размеров, названия- произвольно задаются админом ИМ. У каждого продукта - произвольная комбинация доступных размеров.
Какая должна быть структура базы под эти размеры, каким запросом за раз получить для каталога характеристики товара - основной затык - доступные размеры, все остальное - не принципиально.
Хоботить несколько запросов, потом разбирать php - как-то скучно

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса: вы спроектировать не можете или не знаете какие запросы писать или что?

Comment: Вроде ж классическая связь многие-ко-многим. Таблица товара, таблица размеров и таблица связей товар-размер. В селекте выборка товара, джоин на таблицу связей и ещё один на таблицу размеров. Сгруппировать можно или программно или в запросе через group_concat. Или вообще отдельным запросом вынимать после товара.